# is the GPS network free or available for any device?

Tags: gps, mobile, windows

I have a question (I'm really sorry if is kind of dumb question).

But if I have a device with GPS (smarthphone,pda,pocket pc, etc)

Does the device need any additional service to enable GPS data?

I mean is the GPS network free or available for any device with the appropriate hardware ?

I'm kind of lost and probably I need to use GPS for one application running on windows mobile 6.5

Comment: It's not a dumb question, but the very first paragraph of the [very top hit](http://www8.garmin.com/aboutGPS/) in a Google search for "GPS" answers it directly.

Comment: I'm really sorry, I've been really busy researching about libraries about GPS and the Camera for the device, and didn't notice about that, probably I should look for before ask. (aomm or scary)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it does not show research effort.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yeah, mobiles integrate 2 kinds of GPS, Cell Tower/ Wifi Assistance GPS and the Satellite GPS, both services are free of charge but if you want to display your position on a Map, you need a offline map database or an Internet Connection to get into google maps or another maps service.

Comment: So in short, how Can I know that kind of GPS my device is capable ? probably I'll need check the datasheet specification but my superior hasn't made the selection yet, I suppose Satellital is the most reliable and the one I can manipulate without any external service,I mean get the geodata using just a library or api, I'm gonna develop the app on the compact framework and pretty sure the device it'll run Windows Mobile 6.5

Comment: Well it depends on the End-User specifications, the Cell Tower/Wifi Assistance by Triangulation and IP Geolocation works fine and fast but the accuracy isnt that great, if you want to use Satellital GPS service, you need more time, cause the GPS chip is disabled, and when a request of GPS is made to the device it need to be started and takes some seconds until the service its available.

Answer (score 1):

There are different GPS services like NAVSTAR, GALELIO, GLONASS and all are free for appropriate hardware. they don't even need cellular communication so the only cost is of hardware. Hardware have different prices with higher accuracy costing more. smartphones, pdas have lower accuracy while dedicated GPS recievers like GARMIN have higher accuracy. and then there is military grade devices which are out of limits for civilians, and they have absolute accuracy.

So basically GPS is free, you only pay for device so choose device carefully.